# Java Spring Force developers to set permission annotation at http endpoints

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, reflection

I want to protect all http endpoints with spring security annotations. Is there a way to punish developers that forget setting annotations on methods. Spring configuration? Or do I have to write my own AOP/Reflection code that does this at compile time?

Answer (score -2):

just add spring security core maven dependency on your pom file , with this configuration spring will secure your all endpoints.
it will generate username as user and password will show on your console and you can also configure it manually.

Comment: I have custom security annotations (@Permission) for roles that I need to check against. Every endpoint needs at least one annotation

Comment: That won't throw an error if the endpoints don't contain an `@PreAuthorize`. Nor should you use that like that in production.

Comment: I think I'm fine with a unit test that checks that.